# extracting a string between two quotes in bash

Tags: bash

I have example string like
`Test "checkin_resumestorevisit - Online_V2.mt" Run`

and i want to extract the text between the two quotes in bash. 
I tried using command like

```
SUBSTRING=${echo $SUBSTRING| cut -d'"' -f 1 }
```

but it fails with `error: bad substitution`.

Comment: The "bad substitution" is because you used `${}` instead of `$()`.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are reserved -- see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace -- good practice is to use lower-case names for your own variables to avoid unintentional conflicts with variables with meaning to the system.

Comment: ...also, get in a habit of running things through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here (it also would have called out lack of quotes as a source of bugs).

Answer (score 31):

In order to extract the substring between quotes you can use one of these alternatives:

**Alternative 1:**

```
SUBSTRING=`echo "$SUBSTRING" | cut -d'"' -f 2`
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
SUBSTRING=`echo "$SUBSTRING" | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'`
```

**Alternative 3:**

```
set -f;IFS='"'; SUBSTRING=($SUBSTRING); SUBSTRING=${SUBSTRING[1]};set +f
```

Comment: re: #3, look at what it does if `SUBSTRING='*"foo"'` and this code is run in a non-empty directory. Safer to use `read` to split on IFS.

Comment: ...though really, since the first two don't properly quote the `echo`, they're open to glob-expansion bugs as well. `echo "$SUBSTRING" | ...` if you want to avoid them.

Comment: Thank you @Charles, you are totally right! I fixed the alternatives by taking into account your advices. Particularly the alternative 3 is a horrible workaround, but should work now!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to extract content between the first `"` and the last `"`:

```
s='Test "checkin_resumestorevisit - Online_V2.mt" Run'
s=${s#*'"'}; s=${s%'"'*}
echo "$s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other weird ideas to not let [@arton-dorneles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636517/248390) alone :^)

But my favourite is [@charles-duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636373/248390) answer.

```
[[ "$SUBSTRING" =~ \"(.*)\" ]] && SUBSTRING="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

IFS=\" read -r _ SUBSTRING _ <<<"$SUBSTRING"

# bonus, match either ' or " by pair
SUBSTRING=$(echo "$SUBSTRING" | sed -r "s/.*?([\"'])(.*)\1.*/\2/")
```

Note that bash create a temporary file for "here string" (`<<<`) as it does for here documents.

#### Edit

It took me way too long to fully understand Charles Duffy critics; for readers, this could be when:

```
SUBSTRING='*"inside text" outside text'
```

In this scenario, the following would be unsafe because the star would be expanded, listing files and moving the desired result index:

```
IFS=\" eval '_=($SUBSTRING);SUBSTRING="${_[1]}"'

IFS=\" read -ra _ <<<"$SUBSTRING";SUBSTRING=${_[1]}
```

Comment: Second option here doesn't prevent glob expansion; consider what happens in the `*"foo"` case in a directory containing at least two files. That said, I definitely do like the `read` approach -- fix or redact the buggy suggestion in the middle and this will have my upvote.

Comment: It certainly does expand the `*` for me. How you you expect the code to avoid that?

Comment: If you did `touch 'foo ' 'bar ' baz`, your example in the comment above would show the globbing -- there's no whitespace in IFS, so the space before the first double-quote is being treated as literal, hence the glob finds no matches when the only items to be matched are `foo`, `bar` and `baz` (with no spaces in the names).